# What is "I'm single" in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests

How can I name the state of not being in a relationship? A search for "single" gave me:

- *unuopa* - which I assume is in the sense of "single, not double"
- *solulo* - an alone person, a lonely person, a loner
- *fraŭla* -> (*fraŭlo*) - a man who is not married.  Does this cover men who have a partner but aren't married too? I guess not.

What would you say?

---

Kiel mi nomu la staton de "ne esti en amrilato"? Dum mi serĉis mi trovis *solulo* kaj *fraŭla*. Mi pensas ke oni povas vivi nesole sen ampartnero, kaj fraŭloj estas viroj needziĝintaj, do tiu vorto ne estas ekzakte kion mi serĉas. Kion vi dirus?

Answer (score 6):

The root *fraŭl-* sounds incredibly outdated to me and I would never recommend it in the modern, westernized context where probably most members of this community live. It is available in the language for different situations, and this is a good thing. OTOH, the meaning of *single* we are dealing with is exactly a product of that modern, westernized world. Hence, in my opinion, *fraŭl-* is not a good translation for it.

I agree that there isn’t an universally accepted idiom for *I’m single*. I’ve actually heard *Mi vivas unuopule,* which I like very much: it is different from *Mi vivas unuope* ( = *I live alone* ), and from *Mi estas unuopulo* ( = *I am an individual* ), is immediately understandable, and doesn’t have the negative connotations of *senpartnera* and similar solutions.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, Esperanto does not have a single word for ”single”. You’d have to re-phrase, for example:
*Mi nun ne havas koramik(in)on.* (I don't have a boy/girlfriend) ≈ I’m currently single.

I think being ”single” is a new phenomenon in English as well – earlier people would say ”bachelor”, ”unmarried” etc. In my own language, Danish, it’s similar – we actually borrowed the English word to describe the modern idea of singleness! :-)  (That you’re not ”alone” even if you don’t have a romantic partner.) So, maybe Esperanto hasn’t ”caught up” with this idea yet? We could of course coin ”*senkoramika*”, but doesn’t it sound a bit – heartless?

Comment: Or how about _senpartnera_?

Comment: Yeah! It conveys the idea, but I agree that it feels sad somehow.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is not in Esperanto, but **unclear definition in English** (language).
Google 'define single' gives 4x adjectives, 4x nouns, 4x verbs.

Esperanto is more precise language that avoids typical English ambiguities resolved with idiomatic phrases that need to be considered in context and remember each use.

adj#2. unmarried or not involved in a stable sexual relationship

noun#1. an individual person or thing rather than part of a pair or a group
 . people who are unmarried or not involved in a stable sexual relationship

**fraŭl/o** ~ Ne edziĝinta viro: li estas persista fraŭlo; oni mokas la maljunan fraŭlon k lian noktan ĉapon

EN - EO:

- I'm single. Mi estas **fraŭla**.
- Not a single person arrived late. Eĉ ne unu persono malfruiĝis.
- I'm still single. Mi estas ankoraŭ sola.
- Single or double room? Ĉambro unulita aŭ dulita?
- She's a single mother. Ŝi estas senpartnera patrino.
- I am 40 years old and I am still single. Mi havas kvardek jarojn kaj
  ankoraŭ mi ne eniris geedzecon.

Answer (score 2):

In today's modern society, it is hard to come up with a word to describe someone who is unmarried and doesn't have a girlfriend or boyfriend.

Even if a man said "Mi havas nek koramikinon nek edzinon" it is still not sufficient because he could be gay. Maybe he has a boyfriend or a husband.

Maybe, you could say "Mi estas havebla" but there are problems with that also. Maybe it a person who already married but they are polyamorous.

Comment: Indeed. Also in the last case: they are single, but do not want to be in a relation (and so are not available).

Comment: Good point! If I understand what you're trying to say though, the example should be "Mi havas nek koramikinon nek edzinon."

Comment: Actually, I just thought of "ampartneron". That includes both men and women.

Answer (score 1):

Mi opinias ke "senparula" estas taŭga.

Comment: Mi ne komprenas: tiu vorto estas nek uzata nek strukure senchava: "rilata al persono sen paro"?

Answer (score 0):

Though `(esti) fraŭla` seems to cover one of the meanings, introducing a verbal qualification would seem better.

```
Mi vivas sole.
```

Instead of `esti sola`.